# Stargazer: Save to file, don't show in console

Tags: r, stargazer

When I want to save my regression results with

```
stargazer(regressions[[reg]], out=myFile, out.header=FALSE
```

`stargazer` keeps also displaying/printing the result into the console. As I'm iterating over dozens of results, this ruins my overview and the log. Is there any way to explicitly tell `stargazer` not only to save the output to the file, but also not to print it additionally?

I'm on `stargazer_5.1`.

Comment: What is the value of `myFile`? If it's not something like "path/to/file.ext" then you are seeing the results of an incomplete request.

Comment: @BondedDust the value is `[1] "../log/regressions_ldiffStatus.tex"`, and that path exists.

Answer (score 11):

You can write a function that captures the output of `stargazer` and saves it to a file without any output to the console. For example, adapting code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465255/how-to-suppress-stargazer-information-in-output-file):

```
mod_stargazer <- function(output.file, ...) {
  output <- capture.output(stargazer(...))
  cat(paste(output, collapse = "\n"), "\n", file=output.file, append=TRUE)
}
```

Then, to run the function:

```
mod_stargazer(myfile, regressions[[reg]], header=FALSE)
```

`append=TRUE` results in all your tables being saved to the same file. Remove it if you want separate files for each table.

Comment: Thanks! The use of `cat()` to handle the output of `stargazer()` is useful here and in fact sometimes even necessary to get proper formatting of tables, regardless of whether you want to suppress all the printing to screen.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318860/r-stargazer-manually-specify-r2-and-write-to-tex).

Answer (score 9):

well given the answer of eipi10, the only part you need is

```
bla <- capture.output(stargazer(..., out=output.file))
```

specifying the output file in stargazer and capture the output in something random, which you simply remove or overwrite for the next table.
No need to define a new function.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to approach the problem is:

1. store the output of stargazer in an object without an output file nor capture.output()

`output <- stargazer(..., type="text")`

this stores the output as an nx1 matrix which doesn't look nice so you must convert it in the second step

2. convert the output object into a nice format

2.a) with dplyr:

```
output %>% paste(., collapse = "\n") %>% cat("\n")
```

2.b) without dplyr:

```
cat(paste(output, collapse = "\n"), "\n")
```

2.c) as a function if you really prefer this:

```
print_stargazer <- function(object) {
   cat(paste(object, collapse = "\n"), "\n")
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
output <- stargazer(..., type="text")
print_stargazer(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set working directory. Then if you run the following code, it will save a text file with stargazer results to your working directory folder.

model_results <- stargazer(model1, type = "text")
capture.output(model_results, file = "model1.txt")

Comment: You don't need to set a working directory for this. As the other answers note, you can simply provide a path to whatever output file that you want, and then supply it to the `file` argument.