# R Stargazer - Manually Specify R^2 And Write to .tex

Tags: r, stargazer

I am using Stargazer to report the results from some models where I use robust standard errors.  The process of calculating these and then feeding the models to Stargazer strips out data such as R^2 and so I need to add it in manually.  Doing so, however, is causing me problems.  Below is the basic `stargazer()` call that I'm trying to run.  Following it and some discussion is the code needed to generate the data going into the `stargazer()` call:

```
stargazer(fit1_robust, fit2_robust,
    keep.stat = c("n", "adj.rsq"), # doesn't actually result in keeping the stats, but including it just to demonstrate such.
    add.lines = list(c("Adjusted $R^2$", fit1_r2, fit2_r2)),
    out = "~/Test.tex"
    )
```

When I call this, I get the following error:

```
Error in if (nchar(text.matrix[r, c]) > max.length[real.c]) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

There are some interesting aspects to this:

- The error does not occur if I omit the `^` and instead just use `"Adjusted $R2$"`
- The error does not occur if I don't use the `out` argument to specify a .tex file to export to.

Addressing either of these bullets "solves" the error, but at the expense of my code not really doing what I want it to.  How can I manually add the adjusted R^2 in the way I've done here (and more generally, add notes involving `^`)?

(Note: I also tried escaping the `^` character, replacing it with `/^`.  That gave an error.  If I use a double escape: `//^` that prevents the error, but then a single escape shows up in the generated .tex file and that's not what I want.)

Here is the rest of the code to get to the point of having all objects needed for the above `stargazer()` call:

```
library(stargazer)
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)

#################
# Simulate Data #
#################

N = 100

A = rnorm(N)
B = rnorm(N)
Y = 2*A + B + rnorm(N)
Data = data.frame(Y, A, B)

#####################################
# Fit Models and Find Robust Errors #
#####################################

fit1 = lm(Y~A)
fit2 = lm(Y~A+B)

fit1_robust = coeftest(fit1, vcov = sandwich)
fit2_robust = coeftest(fit2, vcov = sandwich)

fit1_r2 = round(summary(fit1)$adj.r.squared, 4)
fit2_r2 = round(summary(fit2)$adj.r.squared, 4)
```

Comment: instead of `out =` could you just use `x = stargazer(...)` followed by `cat(x, file='Test.tex'`). tested and works for me

Comment: @dww  Great point!  (though, it's also necessary to specify `sep='\n'` in the call to `cat()` ).  If no one else answers, I'd be happy to accept your comment as an answer, since it does solve the problem.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048097/r-robust-ses-and-model-diagnostics-in-stargazer-table?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One workaround is to save the output of stargazer in a variable, then write it to file afterwards:

```
star = stargazer(fit1_robust, fit2_robust,
  add.lines = list(c("Adjusted $R^2$", fit1_r2, fit2_r2))
)
cat(star, sep = '\n', file = 'Test.tex')
```

[image]